# Does Bob Hope hold the record for headlining the most USO tours?

Tags: world-war-two, vietnam-war, korean-war, entertainment, gulf-war

[image]
<sup>Bob Hope entertaining the troops in 1944. *Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Hope)*</sup>

### Question

Multiple sources indicate that Bob Hope headlined 57 [USO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Service_Organizations) tours, including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Hope) and Legacy's article on [Bob Hope's USO](http://www.legacy.com/news/culture-and-trends/article/bob-hopes-uso), among others. I believe this is the record. However, I have been unable to verify this. Is there any documentation indicating anyone else having completed more than 57 USO tours, or can a source be found which indicates Bob Hope's 57 tours is the record?

Additional sources I have consulted:

- Wikipedia's [USO article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Service_Organizations#Honoring_Bob_Hope);
- USO.org - [Bob Hope USO Shows: The One-Man Morale Machine](https://www.uso.org/stories/154-bob-hope-the-uso-s-one-man-morale-machine);
- Biography.com - [Bob Hope](https://www.biography.com/people/bob-hope-9343481);
- CBS News - [A Tribute to Bob Hope: USO Tour](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/a-tribute-to-bob-hope-uso-tour/);
- Bob Hope USO - [About Us](http://bobhopeuso.org/about-us/bob-hope/);
- Library of Congress - [Entertaining the Troops](https://www.loc.gov/exhibits/hope-for-america/entertaining-the-troops.html);
- Library of Congress - [Bob Hope Exhibits](https://www.loc.gov/exhibits/bobhope/uso.html);
- USA Patriotism - [Bob Hope](http://www.usapatriotism.org/stars/bhope.htm);
- [The Daily Beast](https://www.thedailybeast.com/stephen-colbert-bob-hope-and-more-uso-stars-who-entertained-troops-over-70-years) - *which lists "nearly 200 USO performances” by Bob Hope, and I suspect this would also be a record, though I cannot confirm this either.*

I modified the title to indicate "headlined" - but originally I was looking for some unsung hero who may have toured (headlined or not) more than 57 times. Some B-lister or C-lister. I suspect 57 would be the record for headlining though even that has been extremely hard to verify (no sources found yet).

---

**Sidebar**

I love this quote from Bob Hope in 1944 (as found on [this Library of Congress exhibit](https://www.loc.gov/exhibits/hope-for-america/entertaining-the-troops.html)):

> *Believe me when I say that laughter up at the front lines is a very precious thing—precious to those grand guys who are giving and taking the awful business that goes on there. . . . There’s a lump the size of Grant’s Tomb in your throat when they come up to you and shake your hand and mumble “Thanks.” Imagine those guys thanking me! Look what they’re doin’ for me. And for you.* —Bob Hope, 1944

<sup>P.S. Bob - *Thanks for the memories!*</sup>

Comment: Strange that this is not better documented/easier to find. [This even says:](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Bob_Hope) "he headlined approximately sixty tours".

Comment: A record for headlining would be much easier to establish than one for merely performing.

Comment: One is tempted to say Bob Hope has done the most tours but then I saw that Brooke Shields joined him on 27 tours - no idea how many she did with others, though. I think the only option for getting an answer is asking the USO directly.

Comment: @LarsBosteen that may be the only option.  Still not finding anything in searches.

Comment: @LangLangC I was surprised as well - I thought perhaps my Google skills just needed a kick n the pants but there may be more info behind a paywall somewhere that I just don't have access to.  Or perhaps in some book that isn't searchable online.

Comment: @KerryL - please don't respond in comments; edit the question.  I've moved one of the most relevant comments into the question, but I'd like to delete the remainder of the comments. Please edit the question to represent what you want to ask, and clarify whether you're looking for "headline" or "participate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Gary Sinise has done over 100 USO tours.

---

According to an [article at USO.org](https://www.uso.org/stories/2024-gary-sinise-lt-dan-band-performance-marks-actor-s-97th-uso-tour) dated April 18, 2017,

> Gary Sinise & Lt. Dan Band Performance Marks Actor's ***97th*** USO **Tour**

A later article,just last month(Mar 27, 2019), also at [USO](https://www.uso.org/stories/2346-gary-sinise-100-uso-tours), says

> Today, Sinise will perform his **100th USO Tour** in Virginia Beach,
>   Virginia, and we’d like to salute his service to our military
>   community.

---

Since the Questioner stated in the body of the question,

> Is there any documentation indicating anyone else having completed
>   more than 57 USO tours,
>
> ...originally I was looking for some unsung hero who may have toured
>   (headlined or not) more than 57 times.

the Gary Sinise information seems to qualify for at least that part of the question.

Comment: Also, how many of those tours did he headline?

Comment: Though the title *does* say headlining, the body of the question says 'Is there any documentation indicating anyone else having **completed** more than 57 USO tours'. As per OP's comment, ' **some unsung hero who may have toured (headlined or not) more than 57 times**' I think this answer should be allowed to stand.

Comment: @justCal I agree, although I think it may be better if the fact that it's a partial answer dealing with that specific aspect of the question was made explicit in the answer itself, rather than comments - which are ephemeral!

Comment: Yes, I was hoping the answerer might return, and expand his work. If not, perhaps a little more editing will be in order.  I dislike making extensive edits to someone elses work...

Comment: Apples and Oranges, Bob Hope's USO tours Like his WWII south pacific tour in summer of 1944, included more than 150 shows.  I'm sure even Gary Sinise would object with equating 1 show at Virginia beach in peace time with the tours which Hope made traversing 30,000 miles island hopping around the South Pacific in War time.   Not to diminish Gary Sinise but their is really no comparison between him in Hope.